# what should I use for an object/thing/non-living 'What' or 'Who' in a question like this?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, questions

- "Who decides which program to run next?"
- "What decides which program to run next?"
  ***which sentence would be correct if the answer could be 'interpreter' which is an object/non-living thing?***

because ChatGPT says:
*While traditionally "who" is used for people and occasionally animals with human-like traits, in casual or figurative language, people may sometimes use "who" for computer parts or other objects. This usage tends to anthropomorphize or personify the object to create a more engaging or relatable tone.*

*For example:*

*- "Who is responsible for handling the graphics processing in this computer?"

-"Who decides which program to run next?"*

*This usage is not strictly grammatical in a traditional sense, but it is becoming more common in informal contexts, especially when discussing technology or objects in a way that implies agency or decision-making capabilities. However, in more formal or technical writing, it's generally preferable to stick to "what" for inanimate objects or non-human entities.*

another example:
[image]

***WHO*** does it

Comment: Either is fine, as your question documents well.

Comment: The logical reading of those two "who" examples refer to people, not things.

Comment: I feel like the quote answers your question, so it's not clear to me what question remains. Can you use the "edit" button to tell more about why the ChatGPT content doesn't resolve your confusion?

Comment: If chatgpt says *people may sometimes use "who" for computer parts or other objects,* it's talking nonsense. People might well "anthropomorphize" software like chatgpt itself (I caught myself saying ***please*** to it the other day! :) and there will be more of that when such software runs in humanoid robots. But so far I have *never* heard anyone use ***who, he, she,...*** when referring to any aspect of current computer hardware or Operating System job scheduling software. But I thought asking about anything coming from chatgpt was de facto Off Topic here, now.

Comment: @AndyBonner I asked this question again here because I don't really trust ChatGPT. there is "AI Hallucination" where you get answers well fabricated as if they were right but sometimes they aren't, that's why I decided to post the question here and I always prefer this.

Comment: @FumbleFingers you mean 'What' is always used for objects/non-living things.

Comment: That diagram looks to me like chatgpt hallucinated a chimera based on crossing a "corporate responsibility" chart with a computer program flowchart. A "computer control unit" is a thing - a ***what*** - not a "who".

Comment: @FumbleFingers sorry for the misunderstanding but ChatGPT didn't generate the chart, actually, I found that in a pdf about computer architecture that I was reading. however, the answer provided was generated by it.

Comment: Perhaps whoever wrote that pdf just used an existing "personal responsibility" document (about *people*) as a template, but failed to edit the column title. Whatever - it's just rubbish.